# Klein's Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q$ be the projective quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $x_0^2+\cdots+ x_r^2$. In Hartshorne book Ex.II.6.5, Klein's theorem is that

if $r\geq 4$ and if $Y$ is an irreducible subvariety of codimension 1 on $Q$, then there is an irreducible hypersurface $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $V\cap Q=Y$, with multiplicity one.

I seach for the proof or some refference, but I can't find...
Maybe is there some book or refference for the proof?

Comment: Hartshorne does lay out the proof in exercises, along with hints. Take a look at the exercises before II.6.5, specifically II.6.3(c).

Comment: Great hint user115654, +1. Why don't you flesh it out into an answer, so that I (and other users, I'm sure) can have the pleasure of upvoting you?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is that every divisor $Y$ on $Q$ is a complete intersection in $\mathbf P^n$. In other words, if $Y=V(I)\subset\mathbf P^n$ is the structure of closed subscheme, then the homogeneous ideal $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\supset I = (f,g)$ where $f=x_0^2+x_1^2+\cdots+x_r^2$ and $g$ is some irreducible homogeneous polynomial. Truly this is equivalent to showing that every codimension one homogeneous prime of the homogeneous coordinate ring $S(Q)$ is principal, which would be true if $S(Q)$ were factorial. Generally, if $V$ is any projective variety, then $S(V)$ is factorial iff (1) $V$ is projectively normal and (2) $\operatorname{Cl} V\cong\mathbf Z$ and is generated by the class of a hyperplane section. $Q$ is projectively normal from the general result which says that over a field $k$ of characteristic not $2$, $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,z]/(z^2-f)$ is factorial for any squarefree nonconstant polynomial $f$. This satisfies condition (1). When $r\geqq4$ we have that $\operatorname{Cl}Q\cong\mathbf Z$ is generated by a hyperplane section, satisfying (2). This is enough to conclude. (All these statements appear on the same page as the statement of Klein's theorem in Hartshorne's book.)